# Is there a service that can store and mail official transcripts from any school?

Tags: transcript-of-records

I have studied at a number of schools. Most graduate programs require "transcripts from all previous schools". The last time I applied for a program, I spent a full day applying for transcript requests, as each school has different forms, Web systems, payment methods, etc. Is there a service that can hold all student transcripts and mail out official copies when one applies to a new program?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no such service. Receiving universities want their copy to be certified correct by your university and sent in a sealed envelope such that you could not have easily tampered with it. No university is likely to trust anyone but the originating university to handle this process, so such a service has not been created. It would be very easy for some third party to allow you to create a transcript with whatever grades and courses you liked, and only through careful auditing could a university be able to trust that your records were properly transmitted. As such, it's easier, cheaper, and more reliable for the Registrar at each university to handle this on their own.

Comment: Often schools and jobs only need official transcripts at the very end of the process.

Comment: @StrongBad, OK, so what's your point. I don't understand what you're getting at. I can get a copy of my official transcript sent to myself and send scans/photocopies to people who need unofficial copies up front. Then when they need an official copy at the end of the process, I can get that sent. I think that proves that there's even less of a market for a transcript-sending service.

Comment: Sealed *and* dated, should be emphasized. If I were to send a transcript dated from 3 years ago to an application, I could have easily flunked 2 more degrees in that period or something.

Comment: @BillBarth I think you summed up my point. Just because you are applying to a bunch of schools/jobs doesn't mean you need official sealed transcripts for each application. You may only need official transcripts sent to the school you are going to attend.

Comment: @StrongBad, oh, sorry, I thought you were trying to convey something else entirely!